# How can I do natural sort in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, natural-sort

I am trying to sort Jira stories with several potential structures: 3 to 5 characters followed by dash followed by 3 or 4 digits e.g. XXX-###, XXX-####, XXXX-### etc.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sample data and how you want it to sort?

Comment: And can you also share what results you are getting if you have used order by in Snowflake already? In any case wondering if collations might be able to help and worth a look? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/collation.html#collation-support

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by a natural sort, but you can sort by a regex. For example, to get just the number of a JiraID string.

```
--This Returns '123'
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'xx-123' , '\\d+');

--This Returns 'xx'
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'xx-123' , '\\w+');

--So this would sort by just the number in a Jira number column based on the number part
... order by REGEXP_SUBSTR( JiraID , '\\d+')::int;

--This would order first by IDs with the same string, and then order by Number
... order by REGEXP_SUBSTR( JiraID , '\\w+'), REGEXP_SUBSTR( JiraID , '\\d+')::int;
```

More complex examples are possible if you provide a sample input with a desired output ordering